# Культура поведінки №1: етнофолізми / Culture of behavior #1: ethnophaulisms

Tags: discussion, rules, admin-reference

На щастя, я поки що не бачив такого в питаннях, коментарях чи відповідях, але пишу про це про всяк випадок на майбутнє, щоб було на що послатися в разі чого, коли сайт відкриється.

У питаннях, коментарях чи відповідях можуть виникати теми, пов'язані з іншими народами і мовами. Я розумію, що в результаті політичної ситуації, особистого досвіду чи інших причин ставлення людей до тих чи інших країн/народів/мов може бути далеким від нейтрального, але, будь ласка, в будь-якому випадку використовуйте лише нейтральну лексику на позначення інших країн/народів/мов.

Наприклад, про російську мову:

- російська — добре;
- московська — гірше, бо це не є офіційною назвою, але, мабуть, все ж допустимо, бо не є етнофолізмом чи передражнюванням;
- <s>москальська</s>, <s>кацапська</s>, <s>расєйська</s>, <s>руській єзиг</s>, <s>язик</s>, <s>собача</s> тощо — зась.

Щодо впливу російської мови чи російського уряду на українську мову:

- русифікація — найпоширеніше слово <sub>(хоча не зовсім точно виражає суть, бо має корінь -рус-, що зазвичай застосовується до Русі (спільного кореня), а не корінь -рос-, що зазвичай застосовується до Росії (сучасної гілки))</sub>;
- росифікація, зросійщення, росіянізація, помосковщення, змосковщення — мабуть, теж прийнятні, бо не базуються на етнофолізмах чи передражнюванні;
- <s>москалізація</s>, <s>кацапізація</s>, <s>змоскал(ьщ)ення</s>, <s>скацапщення</s> тощо — зась.

Також це стосується назв інших країн/народів/мов: поляки, а не <s>ляхи/пшеки</s>, білоруси, а не <s>бульбаші</s>, євреї, а не <s>жиди</s> <sub>(так, я знаю, що на заході України це слово застосовується з нейтральною конотацією, але все таки наш сайт для всіх, а не лише для мешканців тих регіонів)</sub> тощо.

Хоча це не стосується обговорення цих слів. Ми можемо *обговорювати* лайливу лексику, але не варто *застосовувати* її одне до одного чи третіх осіб. Як би комусь іноді цього не хотілося, але це не найкращий спосіб вирішення проблем.

---

In short: Don't use offensive/mocking vocabulary to other countries/nations/languages within questions, comments and answers. We may *discuss* profanities, but should not *use* them to each other or a third person.

Comment: Why would we care *now*? A whole bunch of SE sites live without specific articles about it; once any profanity or insult appears, **flags** exist just for that purpose, and then the Mods decide wither to edit out or remove the post. But in most cases, regular users help with editing. What's the problem?

Comment: But why, I've [just used «Московське царство» and «поневолені народи»](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/437/8) and I insist on it. :) Also, «примусова русифікація» is a widely accepted term.

Comment: @bytebuster, так «Московське царство» — не етнофолізм.

Comment: But what's wrong with the word москаль? Hasn't it been printed in millions of books during the Soviet “internationalism” days? Even then it wasn't considered an ethnophaulism, what's changed now?.. I stronly disagree with banning this word.

Comment: @YellowSky, historically it has been neutral and had several meanings: Russian/Muscovite, soldier, state servant. During Soviet era old poems and works containing the word "moskal" (e.g. T. Shevchenko) were still published and learned, but their interpretations/reviews/critique were often biased to treat "moskal" more as "soldier"/etc (e.g. to partially neutralize the hatred expressed in Shevchenko's and other poems). Now we can be free of both misinterpreting the words (to make poems to fit some official ideology) and of the need to use slur words ourselves.

Comment: @YellowSky, [today it has become an ethnic slur referring to the Russians living in Russia used in Ukraine, Belarus, and Poland. The term is frequently derogatory or condescending, an equivalent of the Russian term Khokhol for Ukrainians](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moskal). I have nothing against discussing the literature with the word "moskal" (all kinds: where it's used as slur for R., where it's used as neutral for R. and where it's used in other meanings). Still, I don't see any reason to use that word ourselves (except the context of discussing specific usages in literature/history).

Comment: @YellowSky, yes, not everybody considers the word "moskal" as slur nowadays, some still treat it as neutral. But why do we need to use the word that *at least some* of participants consider offensive, if we have fully neutral words (either official "російський"/"росіянин", or unofficial "московський"/"московіт")? BTW, not everybody consider the word "zhyd" as offensive, not everybody consider the word "khokhol" as offensive — do you want do start these discussions too? Isn't it better just to tend to use the words that satisfy everyone (at least, when we have such)?

Comment: @YellowSky, "Do you have any proofs that in Shevchenko's poems that word meant not simply 'Muscovite', but generally 'Russian, soldier, state servant'?" I didn't claim that, you've read my comment uncarefully. I said (and it's a common opinion) that *Soviet critique* often tended to interpret the word "moskal" within Shevchenko's poems (where *I assume* it's used with different meanings, but *mostly* as Russian/Muscovite) as unrelated to Russians/Muscovites (to fit official ideology of nations friendship).

Comment: @Sasha - Dare me, if I still consider Shevchenko a great poet and a guide in my life, but why should I re-interpret his words according to any present-day political situation and the present ruling regime? I lived during Brezhnevizm, Andropovshchina, Perestroika, Kravchuk rule, Kuchmism, and so on, those minor dolls are nothing against the tremendous genius of Shevchenko, none of them dared to distort his prophetic words, but here comes Sasha who wants to amend their mistakes? )))))

Comment: "@YellowSky: none of them dared to distort his prophetic words." They actually dared — that's what I'm talking about. They *dared* to misinterpret his words within official propaganda to make his poems to look "more conforming" to official ideology. Now we're free of that. (Please, read my message more carefully; I still suppose you've misread it.)

Comment: @Sasha - Maybe they did that for you who were imbedded into the official Soviet/state infrastructure, but for millions of simple Ukrainians, peasants living in villages each having a Kobzar at home it meant _nothing_. They didn't read the Soviet newspapers, they didn't watch the Soviet TV, but they read Shevchenko, they embriodered his portraits, they lived Shevchenko, and you cannot deny that (actually, if you know about such attitutde to the Kobzar among the Ukrainians).

Comment: @YellowSky, I don't deny that. I just oppose to what you said smth like "even Soviet regime accepted Shevchenko as is, considering him as neutral". They didn't. They printed his poems but distorted them in official critique (smth like "no, he's not about Russians/Muscovites, he's about soldiers! he has nothing against R.!" in the simplest appearance). And now: (1) we have no more need to misinterpret somebody's words to make them fit official ideology; we can read it as is; (2) on the other hand, we have no need to use ourselves a lexicon, which is considered as offensive at least by somebody.

Comment: @Sasha - Excuse me, but i give a damn to what Soviets thought of Shevshenko. To read his poems as it is, as you said, that's my goal. Whether you like it or not, Shevchenko did call Muscovites  _москалі_, and he did call Jews _жиди_. Since I know of the substantial objections of the Jewich community against the use of the word _жиди_, I would never insist on using that word. But as for the (make-believe) Russian community, there has never been any objections on using _москалі_. Correct me if I'm wrong. Compared to how Russians call Ukrainians now, _москалі_ is just a baby-talk.

Comment: @YellowSky, question #1: do you recall your statement that the word "moskal" was treated fully neutral even at Soviet era? Question #2: Do you agree that nowadays "moskal" has more-or-less-often slur connotations?

Comment: @Sasha - When did I say "the word "moskal" was treated fully neutral even at Soviet era?" I said it was bearable.

Comment: @YellowSky, it was "bearable" but it's meaning was often distorted to make the sense of old texts more fitting to official doctrine. OK, what about question #2?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is announcement, not a genuine question.